# R sf: when should one run computations on the plane (R2) or on the sphere (S2?)

Tags: coordinate-system, r, sf, s2sphere, plane

When should I use S2 computations on the sphere versus project my data and use R2 computations on the plane?

Starting with version 1.0, package `sf` uses now the `s2` package to handle unprojected/geographical coordinates. `s2` carries computations over the sphere, unlike precedent versions <1.0 that were using computations over the plane for some functions and returned the typical error message *although coordinates are longitude/latitude, ... assumes that they are planar*, see [In r-spatial, the Earth is no longer flat](http://In%20r-spatial,%20the%20Earth%20is%20no%20longer%20flat) and [Spherical geometry in sf using s2 geometry](https://r-spatial.github.io/sf/articles/sf7.html).

While previously, a user with unprojected data would almost be advised to project their data, they now really have two options:

- A) choose a projection and use R2 computations on the plane
- B) keep the data unprojected and rely on S2 for computations on the sphere.

Is there any guidance on how to decide for one versus the other? So is the decision between R2 and S2 just a question of precision, the answer being "it depends how good your projection is", or "it depends how big/close to the pole your features are"? Or are there more fundamental differences?

PS: As per version 1.0-6., there are still [several issues](https://github.com/r-spatial/sf/issues/1771) with S2 that would suggest to use R2 in the short term, but hopefully those issues are solvable in the medium term, which is the topic of this question.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, if you really care about precision in terms of great circle distances then use spherical coordinates and spherical geometry operations. You can get an idea of the precision of one vs the other with some test computations of distance or area.

Or if your data spans large parts of the globe and can't be handled well with one planar coordinate system.

BUT it may be that you are working within a regulatory framework that defines distances etc to be on a projected coordinate system. Suppose you have a set of points (XXXX, YYYY) in some local grid coordinates, EPSG:1234, for example. You are asked to find a buffer area 1km from the points. You compute a 1km buffer from those points in that R2 coordinate system. You could also transform the coords to lat-long, compute an S2 buffer region. That would be slightly different to the R2 region, but would be a more accurate buffer for 1km distances walked on the surface of the earth from buffer edge to point. But if your regulatory framework says "all distances are defined using EPSG:1234" then your S2 computation is *wrong* for your jurisdiction.

Many jurisdictions do have legally mandated coordinate systems, so don't try and be clever and think that converting to lat-long, computing on the sphere, and then converting back to EPSG:1234 is a "better" solution to problems.